# Is there a way to accept multiple arities of callback in Rust?

Tags: types, rust

I'm trying to implement syntax sugar for my library so that someone can write `.render(|image| { … })` instead of `.render(|(), image| { … })` if they have no interesting state management going on. I thought I would be able to do this by implementing a trait for all `FnMut(&State, &Image)`, and having a unit implementation for `FnMut(&Image)`. Unfortunately, I get "conflicting implementation" errors when I try to implement this, because there's no reason something can't implement both of those `FnMut` traits.

My current attempt looks like this:

```rust
trait RenderCallback<State> {
    fn render(&mut self, state: &mut State, image: &mut Image);
}

impl<F, State> RenderCallback<State> for F
where
    F: FnMut(&mut State, &mut Image),
{
    fn render(&mut self, state: &mut State, image: &mut Image) {
        self(state, image)
    }
}

impl<F> RenderCallback<()> for F
where
    F: FnMut(&mut Image),
{
    fn render(&mut self, state: &mut State, image: &mut Image) {
        self(&mut (), image)
    }
}
```

Is there some way to achieve this effect?

Comment: If they have no interest in state management, why not just `.render(|_, image| {...})`?

Comment: @zrzka I'm guessing that the state is a user-specified generic type, so they have to provide *something*. I also think the question is more about how to remove that "unneeded" parameter at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the only way is to use [auto traits](https://doc.rust-lang.org/unstable-book/language-features/optin-builtin-traits.html) with opt out if you want stick with this design. But it requires nightly. An example:

```rust
#![feature(optin_builtin_traits)]

// Implement DummyState for everything ...
auto trait DummyState {}
// ... but opt-out for ()
impl !DummyState for () {}

trait RenderCallback<State> {
    fn render(&mut self, state: &mut State, num: u8);
}

// Implement render callback for any type that implements DummyState
impl<F, State> RenderCallback<State> for F
where
    F: FnMut(&mut State, u8),
    State: DummyState, // DummyState means any type except opted out ()
{
    fn render(&mut self, state: &mut State, num: u8) {
        self(state, num)
    }
}

// Implement render callback for (), which doesn't implement DummyState,
// so there's no overlap
impl<F> RenderCallback<()> for F
where
    F: FnMut(u8),
{
    fn render(&mut self, _state: &mut (), num: u8) {
        self(num)
    }
}

fn with_state() {
    struct MyState {
        x: u8,
    };

    println!("with_state...");
    let mut state = MyState { x: 0 };
    let mut callback = |state: &mut MyState, num: u8| {
        state.x += num;
        println!("{}", state.x);
    };
    callback.render(&mut state, 1);
    callback.render(&mut state, 2);
    callback.render(&mut state, 3);
}

fn without_state() {
    println!("without state...");
    let mut callback = |num: u8| {
        println!("{}", num);
    };
    callback.render(&mut (), 1);
    callback.render(&mut (), 2);
    callback.render(&mut (), 3);
}

fn main() {
    with_state();
    without_state();
}
```